# How do I switch/add Firestore to an existing firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have an existing Firebase project with an empty real time database.  I want to switch/add the new Firestore beta but I don't see any option in the dashboard to add it.  If I click on `Database` in the left menu, all I see is the realtime database.

How do I add/enable the Firestore beta on a project using the dashboard admin?

Do I have to delete the existing real-time database?  Or can they exist side-by-side on the same project?

I don't see the drop down in my dashboard like others have mentioned.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `Database` on the left menu and then click on the drop down menu as shown in the screenshot and from there you select the interface you want to work on (real time DB or Firestore).

[image]

Comment: Unfortuantely I don't see the dropdown in my dashboard - is there something else that might be preventing it?

Comment: I logged out and refreshed my dashboard and now I seem to see it... must have been a cached dashboard I guess.

Comment: Are any modifications needed to the firebase config json when migrating from realtime db to firestore? I see that the databaseURL: "https://xxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com", matches the url shown  in the realtime db console, but the firestore constore does not have a url, just the xxxx-xxxx app name.